# Youtube video embed not working: "Movie Not Loaded..."?

Tags: flash, youtube, youtube-api, video-embedding

I have a site, [advocatedaily.com](http://advocatedaily.com/), which has a Youtube video on the home page that just stopped loading for no reason. Instead, I get a transparent Flash object. Right clicking on it displays "movie not loaded...".

On [other pages on this site](http://advocatedaily.com/advocatetv/), videos are working fine. This occurs on all browsers and on all machines that I've tried it on, so I don't believe it has anything to do with cache or cookies.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this? Why would this occur so suddenly without user influence?

```
<object width="460" height="337"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="460" height="337"></embed></object>
```

[image: movie not loaded annotation, flash, youtube]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the embed code was missing the `video_id`:

```
<embed  src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{VIDEO_ID_HERE}?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave- flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="460" height="337"></embed>
```